# Powershell using .net System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher to get lastLogonTimestamp value

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

before I was using Get-QADUser cmdlet. However when trying to get over 200,000 users, there is a memory leak, and it took 2 days to get all the users. I found a faster method here: https://blog.schmijos.ch/2013/09/27/ad-export-with-get-qaduser-is-too-slow/

This is using the System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher .net class. The issue I am having, is a couple timestamp attributes are not being extracted in the value that Get-QADUser was extracting them.

For example...

User Property lastLogonTimestamp
Get-QADUser = **10/15/2014  7:27:03 AM**
System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher = **130578568233067000**

User Property AccountExpires
Get-QADUser = **3/29/2008  9:00:00 PM**
System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher = **128513232000000000**

Using the `System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher`, is there anyway I can get the result **value** to be the `date` instead of `some really big number`?

Get-QADUser Code:

```
Get-QADUser -sizelimit 0 -LdapFilter "(&(objectCategory=User)(samAccountType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=805306368))" -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties -IncludedProperties SamAccountName,lastLogonTimestamp,AccountExpires,FirstName,LastName,distinguishedName,employeeNumber,employeeID,description,extensionattribute8,userAccountControl | 
select SamAccountName,lastLogonTimestamp,AccountExpires,FirstName,LastName,distinguishedName,employeeNumber,employeeID,description,extensionattribute8,userAccountControl |
Export-Csv $csvFileWithPath -NoTypeInformation
```

System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher code

```
$domain = "LDAP://www.example.com"
$outfile = 'C:\Scripts\Tests\test1.csv'
$properties = "SamAccountName", "lastLogonTimestamp", "AccountExpires", "FirstName", "LastName", "distinguishedName", "employeeNumber", "employeeID", "description", "extensionattribute8", "userAccountControl"

Write-Host "Searching AD..."
$dn = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($domain)
$ds = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($dn)
$ds.Filter = '(&(objectCategory=User)(samAccountType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=805306368))'
$ds.PageSize=1000
$ds.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange($properties)
$list = $ds.FindAll()

# The AD results are converted to an array of hashtables.
Write-Host "Exporting" $list.Count "Records..."
$table = @()
foreach($item in $list) {
    $hash = @{}
    foreach($name in $properties){
        if($item.Properties[$name]){
            $hash.$name = $item.Properties[$name][0]
        }else{
            $hash.$name = $null
        }
    }
    $table += New-Object PSObject -Property $hash
}
$table | Export-Csv $outfile –encoding "unicode" -NoTypeInformation

$inputResultsFile = $outfile
$OutputResultsFile = 'C:\Scripts\Tests\testResults.csv'

Import-Csv $outfile | Export-Csv $OutputResultsFile -NoTypeInformation

Write-Host "Done."
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to convert the dates between the two above using the following (in both cases):

```
(get-date 130578568233067000).AddHours(14025305)
```

So if you do the same - take the number that the .NET method gives you, let Get-Date turn it into a number, and then add those hours it should work.

Comment: Still a bit new to powershell. I'm not sure where I would insert this line in the 2nd code snippet. I've tried setting another if condition for `$name -eq "lastLogonTimestamp"`, then using the try `$hash.([datetime]$name).Date = $item.Properties[$name][0]` and catch `$hash.$name = $item.Properties[$name][0]`. But this has made no difference.

Comment: ah I added this line and it works...  `$tableFixedlastLogonTimestamp = $table | % {if ($_.lastLogonTimestamp) {$_.lastLogonTimestamp = ([datetime]$_.lastLogonTimestamp).Date};$_}`

Comment: Yeah - that's casting it as a date time.  Very nice.  Does it come out with the right year?

Comment: it works for `lastLogonTimeStamp`, but for `AccountExpires` I'm getting an error `Cannot convert value "9223372036854775807" to type "System.DateTime". Error:`. Oh, I just realized it's also not converting it to the right year...

Comment: Alright, I fixed the year issue with the `FromFileTime`, so this line `$tableFixedlastLogonTimestamp = $table | % {if ($_.lastLogonTimestamp) {$_.lastLogonTimestamp = ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)).ToString('g')};$_}`. Now I am still getting an error for `AccountExpires`. The issue appears to be trying to convert this number `9223372036854775807`.

Comment: Okay I have the answer. Create an array of `$listOfBadDateValues = '9223372036854775807', '9223372036854770000', '0'`. Then if `$listOfBadDateValues -contains $_.AccountExpires` do `$_.AccountExpires = $null` else `$_.AccountExpires = ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_.AccountExpires)).ToString('g')`. I also had to input a nested if condition to check for max value of `12/31/1600 5:00 PM`

Answer (score 0):

Convert lastLogonTimestamp using `DateTime` class `FromFileTime` static method; e.g.:

```
Get-ADUser username -properties lastLogonTimestamp |
  Select-Object DistinguishedName,
  @{Name="lastLogonTimestamp"; Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}}
```

Comment: Get-ADUser already does this. I was looking for how to do it with System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher class. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Same answer if you are using the `DirectorySearcher` class.